# How to write a remove method?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, methods, remove-method

Write a method called get which will return an element from the given index. Returns -1 if the index is out-of-bounds.

Write a method called remove which will remove an element from the given index. Returns -1 if the index is out-of-bounds. Data should be shifted accordingly during removal.

```
//This is the get method 

public int get(int index){

    if(index < 0 || index >= size) {
       return -1;

 }else {
        return data[index];
    }

}

//This is the remove method

public int remove(int index){

    if(index < 0 || index >= size){
        return -1;

    }else {

        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
            index[i] = index[i+1];
        }
    }

}
```

This is as far as I got. Not sure how to proceed with the code. I'd appreciate if someone could guide me through. Thank you!

Comment: You need to post the code of the data structure that you are manipulating.

Comment: `index[i]`?? isn't `index` an integer parameter of your method and not an array?

Comment: index[i] should be an array not a variable int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, you have the right idea.  I am going to assume based on your syntax, that you are using an array.  Your `get()` method looks good, but you are missing some code from your `remove()` method.

```
public int remove(int index){
  //check for out-of-bounds
  if(index < 0 || index >= size) //assumes size is set to the size of the array
  {
    return -1; }
  else
    {
     for(int i = index; i < size-1; i++){
         data[i] = data[i+1]; }
         data[size-1] = 0;  //assuming the array contains numbers, if not replace '0' with null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the following :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        index[i] = index[i+1];
    }
```

with:

```
    for(int i = index; i < size-1; i++) {
        data[i] = data[i+1];
    }
```

- Start the loop with `index`
- `index[i]` won't compile. Should be `data[i]` probably.

**Note:**
This will not delete the last element. You need to specifically check for it.

Comment: In addition, the last element should be set null to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MyList<T> {

T[] items = (T[])new Object[10];

public int size() {
            
            int counter=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i ++) {
                   
                if (items[i] != null) {
                     counter ++;
                }
                   
            }
            return counter;
          }

    public void remove(int t) {
            for (int i = t; i < items.length-1; i++) {
                
                items[i]=items[i+1];        
            }
            
            items[items.length-1]=null;
            
            items= Arrays.copyOf(items,size());     
                        
        }
}
```